# How can I fix the issue "rc.exe not found" in Visual Studio 2022? "

Tags: visual-studio, fortran, intel-fortran, visual-studio-2022, intel-oneapi

Premise: I'm completely new to Fortran programming and to the Visual Studio environment.

I've created a very simple Fortran project in Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2022 (the source file is a .f90 file).
The code is the following one:

```
program Sum_Main
    
    double precision :: a,b,c
    
    a = 100.d0
    b = 60.0d0
    c = a+b
    
    write(6,'(f8.2)') c
    
end program Sum_Main
```

I'm in debug mode and when I compile the project everything is ok. But when I press "Build solution", I get the error: "rc.exe not found".

[image]

How can I solve?

Here the Intel software development kits I've installed:
[image]

Comment: I strongly recommend to first learn to use the compiler in your command line. Just the very simple sequence `ifort sum.f90 -o sum.exe` and `sum.exe` is enough.

Comment: There are many Google hits for 'rc.exe not found Intel Fortran'. Most from the Intel.support forum. E.g. https://community.intel.com/t5/Intel-Fortran-Compiler/rc-exe-not-found-when-compiling-or-recompiling/td-p/1119970  You are missing some Visual C++ components. How *exactly* did you install the Visual Studio and the Intel compiler? Did you use the current oneAPI version? Did you follow the instructions?

Comment: Thank you @VladimirF! First of all I've installed Microsoft Visual Studio community 2022 by using my academic e-mail, during the installation I've selected no additional components. Then I've installed Intel oneAPI base toolkit and then Intel oneAPI HPC toolkit by using offline installers (I've added an image to show the webpage for Intel compiler installation).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem Solved! I've reinstalled C++ build tools within workloads group!